# Spy on onClick for Button - React-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I'm trying to get this form working for the first time and would just like to know that my onclick is at least working.  I'd like to inject a spy to replace the handler that my dispatchToProps is referencing as well.

So in other words I'd like to replace this:

```
AsyncActions.login
```

with `loginSpy`

I can't just do `button.props().login = loginSpy` because props are immutable at that point.  I get `TypeError: Can't add property login, object is not extensible`

So is there a way to use restructuring through an ES6 class, specifically an ES6 react component via its constructor or something like that?

I know you can do `{prop1, prop2}` as a parameter in a stateless function, for example:

```
function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
```

but what about ES6 classes in React?

**Test**

```
   it.only('can log in successfully', async () => {
      const container = shallow(<LoginContainer store={store} />),
        loginContainer = shallow(<LoginContainer store={store} />),
        login = loginContainer.dive().find(Login),
        loginForm = login.dive().find(LoginForm),
        loginFormLogin = await loginForm.props().login(),
        button = loginForm.dive().find('.ft-login-button'),
        loginSpy = spy()

        button.props().login = loginSpy
        button.simulate('click')

        expect(loginSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true
    })
```

**Container**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import * as AsyncActions from '../actions/User/UserAsyncActions'
import Login from '../components/Login/Login'

class LoginContainer extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    // const requested = this.user.requested
  }
  render(){
    return( <Login login={this.props.login} /> )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    requesting: state.user.requesting,
    token: state.user.token,
    session: state.user.session
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  login: AsyncActions.login
}

export { Login }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)
```

**LoginForm**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap'

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='ft-login-form'>
        <PageHeader className='ft-header'>Login</PageHeader>
        <form>
          <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText" >
            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-username"
              componentClass="input"
              placeholder="Enter mail"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="text"
            />
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-password"
              componentClass="input"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="text"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            className='ft-login-button'
            onClick={this.props.login}
            type='submit'>Login</Button>
        </form>
      </div>)
  }

}

export default LoginForm
```

Comment: Why use a spy? Can you not console log out something on click?

Answer (score 0):

You should shallow render `LoginForm` instead of `LoginContainer` and simply pass `loginSpy` as a prop to `LoginForm` to test the button...

```
  it.only('can log in successfully', async () => {
      const loginSpy = spy(),
        loginForm = shallow(<LoginForm login={loginSpy} />),
        button = loginForm.dive().find('.ft-login-button')

      button.simulate('click')

      expect(loginSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true
  })
```